# How to get JSON data from WP REST API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

For a long time I've being working on how to get access to my WordPress posts. I'm using WP REST API plugin with the WP REST API - OAuth 1.0a Server, and I get an "401 - Only authenticated users can access the REST API" error.

I've read all the documentation and I touched the `.htaccess`, and I'm going crazy. Please someone help I don't know what to do, and I'm about to give up.

I tried add some code in the `.htaccess` file, and also tried AJAX and JavaScript fetch, and nothing seems to work. I know there are people using it. It'd be nice someone can tell me how to fix this, I really need it.

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: 'http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
   method: 'GET',
   crossDomain: true,
   beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode( 'username:password' ) );
   },
   success: function( data, txtStatus, xhr ) {
       console.log( data );
       console.log( xhr.status );
   }
});
```

Do I need to add any code to the `.htaccess` file? And if so what and where should I put it? Or what is need to make this work. I'm very desperate.

The error:

```
{
  "code": "rest_cannot_access",
  "message": "Only authenticated users can access the REST API.",
  "data": {
    "status": 401
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume you've change `'username:password'` to actually *be* the username and password you set? Also, that is *very very* far from being secure in any way.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes mister, I didn't put it here my real username and password for security

Comment: What Rory is trying to tell you, I think, is that passing your real username and password in a request that way isn't safe. Are you sure that's how the plugin developer recommends to do it?

Comment: Hello @cabrerahector ah ok ok, yes I know it's not safe but I'm just testing, I just want to work.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to pass fields to store credentials. Add this fragment to your AJAX call

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
```

Your call should look something like this:

```
Query.ajax({
 url: 'http://laprensainsolita.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
 method: 'GET',
 crossDomain: true,
 xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
 beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
   xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode( 
             'username:password' ) );
 },
   success: function( data, txtStatus, xhr ) {
   console.log( data );
   console.log( xhr.status );
 }
});
```

Comment: Hello Yuri thanks but now I get this error = Base64 is not defined

Comment: Replace xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.encode( 
             'username:password' ) ); with   xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('myuser:mypswd'));